# jqgrid not able to load data in my Jsp

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jqgrid

When I click a link it should load my jqGrid with some data. I am converting the data to be displayed into json and trying to populate the data. I checked my json object (for conversion I am using Gson().tojson(listObject)) and its printing correctly.

However onClick   **Data=localhost:8080/App/jsp/servlet?Param1=xxxx&Param2=333**, I am not able to load the data, I did some investigation using Firebug and F12 developer, found out that request its not being sent to servlet to  fetch the data. Not sure what is wrong. I am new to JqGrid can some one point my errors?

```
<link type="text/css"   href="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/src/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
jQuery("#jqqGrid").jqGrid({

    url: data,  // the data is 
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',   // tried with POST as well as GET
    colNames: ['ID','Name', 'From Date', 'To Date', 'Status'],
    colModel: [
           {name:'Id', index:'Id', width:55 },
           {name: 'name', index:'name', width:90},
           {name: 'from_Date', index: 'from_date', width: 90},
           {name: 'to_Date', index: 'to_date', width: 90},
           {name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 90},
               ],
    rowNumber:10,
    sortname: 'emp_Id',
    pager: '#jqqGrid_pager',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder:'desc',
    caption:'Employee Leave List',
    onSelectRow: function(){
        var sel = jQuery("#jqqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        alert(sel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to explicitly set the url and trigger inside your onclick function as below

```
 $('#jqqGrid').setGridParam({url : data});
                                    $('#jqqGrid').trigger("reloadGrid", [ {page : 1} ]);
```